# Button not displaying at end of gridview

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

There is dynamic gridview in my application which has "Load More" button at the end and when I click "Load more", more images from api get loaded. Now there are two problems:

1. I want the gridview to appear at full screen when it's first loaded and when I scroll to the bottom of it, "Load More" button should be there. I have tried using scrollview, but no luck.
2. When I click Load More, data gets loaded fine in the gridview, but it takes me all the way up to the top of the gridview. I want to stay at the bottom when I click "Load More" button. I am not even using `NotifyDataSetChanged()`. Here is my xml:

   ```
               <GridView
                   android:id="@+id/lv1"
                   android:numColumns="2"
                   android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

               <Button
                   android:layout_below="@id/lv1"
                   android:id="@+id/loadMore"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="Load More"
                   android:textColor="#fff"
                   android:background="@color/blue"/>
               <ProgressBar
                   android:visibility="gone"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_below="@id/loadMore"
                   android:id="@+id/loader"/>



           </RelativeLayout>
       </ScrollView>

       <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/no_internet"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:visibility="gone"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <include
               layout="@layout/no_internet"/>
       </RelativeLayout>
       <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/no_data"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:visibility="gone"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <include
               layout="@layout/not_found"/>
       </RelativeLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Comment: Do you mean when you open the app, the girdview appear at all the screen, when you scroll to the bottom, the "learn more" button appears. When you click "learn more" button, gridview shows more deta with images, and it saty at the bottom?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT no. When I open the app, the height of the gridview is not as the height of the screen. I want the height of the gridview to cover the whole screen and then at the end, when all the images are loaded into the gridview, I want a button at the end of the gridview.

Comment: Do you try to set the `layout_height` of GridView to match_parent to make it as big as its parent? For the butto at the end of the gridview, it seems that you use the right layout_below. Could you provide the code sample for me to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so here is the solution for this:
I used `android:fillViewport="true"` in the scrollview and everything is as aligned now as I wanted. I hope it helps someone. Cheers !!